# Error when updating MySQL database using UPDATE - SET - WHERE method in Eclipse

Tags: java, mysql, database, eclipse, syntax

I am making a program using Eclipse that allows the user to update the volume of chemicals everytime they’re restocked/used, which requires them to enter the ID of the chemical and the amount they would like to add/subtract. A query is then performed to search for the chemical's ID in the database, and its volume is updated accordingly.

However, I’m having difficulties getting the volume to update. I tried adapting MySQL’s UPDATE statement from [this website](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/jdbc-update-records.htm) to SET volume = volume + amount added, WHERE chemical ID = ID entered by the user; however, there appears to be some syntax errors in my code, more specifically at the UPDATE - SET - WHERE line:

```
public void IDEnter() {
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:8889/StockControlSystem","root","root");
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
        String sql = "Select * from Chemicals where `Chemical ID` ='" + txtChemical_ID.getText()+"'";
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
        if(rs.next()) {
            stmt.executeUpdate("UPDATE Chemicals" + "SET `Volume` = rs.getInt(Volume) + Integer.parseInt(AmountAdded.getText()) WHERE `Chemical ID` in (txtChemical_ID.getText())");
        }
        else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid chemical ID");
            txtChemical_ID.setText(null);
        }
    } catch(Exception exc) {
        exc.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Since I'm still new to MySQL, can someone help me correct this? Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your whole query is badly formatted. Change your code to this:

```java
stmt.executeUpdate("UPDATE Chemicals SET Volume = " +
 rs.getInt(Volume) + Integer.parseInt(AmountAdded.getText())
 + " WHERE Chemical_ID in (" + txtChemical_ID.getText() +  ")");
```

You cannot use `'` single quotes when defining Column names in queries. Single quotes are used for string values!

Still, this would not be the best way to do this. use `PreparedStatement`!

This way:

```java
String updateString = "UPDATE Chemicals SET Volume = ? WHERE Chemical_ID in (?)"; // Creation of the prepared statement, the ? are used as placeholders for the values
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = con.prepareStatement(updateString);
preparedStatement.setInt(1, rs.getInt(Volume) + Integer.parseInt(AmountAdded.getText())); // Setting the first value
preparedStatement.setString(2, txtChemical_ID.getText()); // Setting the second. I am supposing that this txtChemical_ID textField has values seperated by commas, else this will not work!
preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
```

If you need to read more for `PreparedStatement` there are a lot of great [resources](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-use-preparedstatement-in-java/) out there. They also protect against SQL injections.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem might be with the "rs.getInt(Volume)"

Yours:

```
    "UPDATE Chemicals" + "SET `Volume` = rs.getInt(Volume)
+ Integer.parseInt(AmountAdded.getText()) 
WHERE `Chemical ID` in (txtChemical_ID.getText())"
```

Can you try this:

```
 "UPDATE Chemicals" + "SET `Volume` = " + 
Integer.parseInt(AmountAdded.getText()) + " 
WHERE `Chemical ID` in (" + (txtChemical_ID.getText()) +")"
```